# How activities in a pipeline get executed in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline that consists of 4 different activities. Each activity is a prerequisite for the next one. That is, the first activity generates the input for the second activity, the second one generates the input for the third one, etc. I have defined all the input and output folders as tables and in my pipeline I added the output of each job as the input for the next one.

My assumption is that each activity gets executed and generate the output folder and then the next activities takes it as the input. However when I execute the pipeline, the first activity successfully finishes, however when executing the second activity it looks like the first activity is getting executed because the second activity fails and the error message shows that the first activity was being executed and it failed (because I didn't pass the required parameters)! Am I missing something in the way activities are being executed?

My activities are HDInsight activities.

I'm coming from an Oozie background and think of the pipeline as the oozie workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the availability configuration setting in the output data table determines when the activity is run. 
You can try and split the jobs into separate pipelines. I also think that it will be easier to view in the diagram that way and debug the entire flow.

Edit: You can chain activities in a pipeline [chaining activities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution/#chaining-activities) using the system variables (WindowsStart etc.). but I still think that from visual and debug aspect is easier to separate the activities to pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

A pipeline consists of 1-n activities and each activity in a pipeline can have 0-n inputs and 1-n outputs. You can [chain activities](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution/#chaining-activities) in a pipeline and set the pipeline [active period](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-create-pipelines/) i.e. start and end to execute the activities in a pipeline.